# Flask + API VK. Создание опросного-бота

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, flask

Добрый вечер! Решил создать опрос-бота для ВК на Python, использовал микрофреймворк flask. Код:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, каждый раз, когда идет запрос на сервер (Т.е когда пользователь шлет сообщение в личку группы) у меня вызывается функция `processing` и далее по накатанной. Но мне нужно, чтобы после того, как пользователь отправил определенный символ ('1', допустим) у меня вызывалась уже новая функция (начало опроса). В этой функции задавался бы первый вопрос, потом пользователь на него отвечал, потом задавал бы второй вопрос и т.д

Как это можно реализовать? Как запустить функцию при вводе определенного символа знаю. А как сделать так, чтобы сообщение в этой функции выводилось только тогда, когда пользователь отвечал на предыдущее?

Пример выходных данных:

> Б - бот, П - пользователь
>
> (Б): Напишите "1", чтобы начать опрос
>
> (П): 1
>
> (Б): Как вы относительно к stackoverflow?
>
> (П): Положительно
>
> (Б): Как вы относительно к python?
>
> (П): Нормально
>
> (Б): Спасибо за прохождение опроса!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так. Создал бы базу данных (колонки id и status), куда после того, как пользователь отправит 1, я бы записывал его id и status (Например status=1 т.е. начало опроса). И каждый раз, когда приходит новое сообщение, надо смотреть - есть ли запись с id человека, который написал. И если он есть в базе, то надо смотреть - какой status, и отталкиваясь от него отправлять что нужно.

Пример [кода](https://github.com/MrSmitix/BotPollsVK):

```
import sqlite3  # Модуль для работы с SQLite
import vk_api  # Модуль для работы с VK API
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType  # Работа с LongPoll

# Путь + название до файла базы данных
DATABASE = 'database.sqlite3'
# Токен группы (можно переписать программу под бота-пользователя)
TOKEN = '37f311ce7a6a23243ddba80342b3e6ec462f54ae74fe1cf7803a09288e1761781aa899c0dd939f6ded9c5'

# Сообщение отправляемое в начале опроса
MSG_START = 'Для начала опроса напишите 1.'
# 1 вопрос и варианты ответа
QUESTION_1 = 'Как вы относитесь к StackOverflow?\n\n1. Хорошо\n2. Плохо\n\nОтправьте мне номер подходящего варианта.'
# 2 вопрос и варианты ответа
QUESTION_2 = 'Как вы относитесь к python?\n\n1. Хорошо\n2. Плохо\n\nОтправьте мне номер подходящего варианта.'
# 3 вопрос и варианты ответа
QUESTION_3 = 'Может у вас есть что нам сказать? Напишите. Если нет то просто напишите 1.'
# Сообщение отправляемое в конце отпроса
MSG_END = 'Спасибо за прохождение опроса! Ваше мнение очень важно для нас!'


# Класс для работы с пользователем
class User(object):
    # здаем объект юзер
    def __init__(self, user_id):
        self.id = None
        self.user_id = None
        self.status = None

        self.question_1 = None
        self.question_2 = None
        self.question_3 = None

        self.db = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

        self.get_user_data(user_id)
        pass

    # Я понимаю что за это мне стоит отрубить руки, но опять же, это все на скорую руку
    # Я понял где я залажал, но уже поздно)
    # Записываем ответ пользователя
    def set_answer1(self, answer):
        self.cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET question_1 = ? WHERE user_id = ?;', [answer, self.user_id])
        self.db.commit()
        pass
    def set_answer2(self, answer):
        self.cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET question_2 = ? WHERE user_id = ?;', [answer, self.user_id])
        self.db.commit()
        pass
    def set_answer3(self, answer):
        self.cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET question_3 = ? WHERE user_id = ?;', [answer, self.user_id])
        self.db.commit()
        pass

    # Устаналиваем статус прозождения опроса
    def set_status(self, status):
        self.cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET status = ? WHERE user_id = ?;', [status, self.user_id])
        self.db.commit()
        pass

    # Запись в класс из базы данных
    def get_user_data(self, user_id):
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=?', [user_id])
        data = self.cursor.fetchall()
        if not data:
            self.cursor.execute('insert into users(user_id) values (?)', [user_id])
            self.db.commit()

            self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=?', [user_id])
            data = self.cursor.fetchall()

            self.filling(data)
        else:
            self.filling(data)
        pass
    def filling(self, data):
        self.id = data[0][0]
        self.user_id = data[0][1]
        self.status = data[0][2]

        self.question_1 = data[0][3]
        self.question_2 = data[0][4]
        self.question_3 = data[0][5]
        pass


# Главная функция программы
def main():
    print('Бот для проведения опросов.\n')

    # Авторизация и подключение к LongPoll
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=TOKEN)
    vk = vk_session.get_api()
    longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

    # Начинаем слушать...
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
            # Если мне пришло новое, не пустое сообщение то...

            # Просто по тому что я могу
            user_id = event.user_id

            # Консоль не любит emoji и некоторые символы, так что избавимся от случайного exception-а
            text = str(event.text)

            # Объясвляем класс для работы с юзером и передаем в него id пользователя
            user = User(user_id)


            # Самая интересная и по идиотски реализованная часть
            # Тут мне подробно комментировать лень, по этому разбирайтесь сами
            # Можете заглядывать в class User

            if user.status == 'START' and text == '1':
                vk.messages.send(user_id=user_id, message=QUESTION_1)
                user.set_status('QUESTION_1')
                print('vk.com/id{} -> Начинает прохождение опроса'.format(user_id))
                continue

            if user.status == 'START':
                vk.messages.send(user_id=user_id, message=MSG_START)
                print('vk.com/id{} -> Зарегистрирован'.format(user_id))
                continue

            if user.status == 'QUESTION_1':
                if text == '1' or text == '2':
                    user.set_answer1(text)
                    user.set_status('QUESTION_2')
                    vk.messages.send(user_id=user_id, message=QUESTION_2)
                    print('vk.com/id{} -> Ответил на 1 вопрос, переходит к 2'.format(user_id))
                else:
                    vk.messages.send(user_id=user_id, message='Нет такого варианта ответа!')
                continue

            if user.status == 'QUESTION_2':
                if text == '1' or text == '2':
                    user.set_answer2(text)
                    user.set_status('QUESTION_3')
                    vk.messages.send(user_id=user_id, message=QUESTION_3)
                    print('vk.com/id{} -> Ответил на 2 вопрос, переходит к 3'.format(user_id))
                else:
                    vk.messages.send(user_id=user_id, message='Нет такого варианта ответа!')
                continue

            if user.status == 'QUESTION_3':
                if not text == '1':
                    user.set_answer3(text)
                    print('vk.com/id{} -> Ответил на 3 вопрос. Для него опрос окончен.'.format(user_id))
                user.set_status('END')
                vk.messages.send(user_id=user_id, message=MSG_END)
                continue


# Если нас запускают, а не подключают к какому то проекту то...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Запускаем главную функцию
    main()
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы привести пример Вашего решения. Всем бы было интересно.

Comment: Сам бот я выкладывать не стану так как это моя интеллектуальная собственность :D Но если вы считаете, что многим будет интересно, то я сейчас сяду и сделаю небольшой пример. Думаю что за 20 минут справлюсь.

Comment: Да, именно это я и имел ввиду, только (по возможности воспроизводимый) пример. Не сочтите за труд. А киллометры кода находящиеся в интелектуальной собственности на данном ресурсе и не надо.

Comment: Готово. Версия очень сырая, но работает. https://github.com/MrSmitix/BotPollsVK

Comment: Забыл сказать о том что это реализация на long-poll-е, но её можно переписать под Flask и CallBack API довольно таки легко